# How do i assign two PointF points to the method?

Tags: c#, winforms

This is the method of ja72:

```
public static List<PointF> DistributePoints(PointF pt1, PointF pt4, int number_of_points)
        {
            List<PointF> result = new List<PointF>();
            float x_min = Math.Min(pt1.X, pt4.X), x_max = Math.Max(pt1.X, pt4.X);
            float y_min = Math.Min(pt1.Y, pt4.Y), y_max = Math.Max(pt1.Y, pt4.Y);
            if (number_of_points < 2) throw new ArgumentException("Need Two Points At Least");
            for (int i = 0; i < number_of_points; i++)
            {
                float scale = (float)i / (number_of_points - 1);
                float x = x_min + (x_max - x_min) * scale, y = y_min + (y_max - y_min) * scale;
                result.Add(new PointF(x, y));
            }
            return result;
        }
```

And this is how im using it:

```
for (int i = 0; i < clouds.Count - 1; i += 2)
            {
                extendedPoints = DistributePoints(new PointF(clouds[i].X, clouds[i].Y), new PointF(clouds[i + 1].X, clouds[i + 1].Y), 20);
            }
            clouds = extendedPoints;
            return clouds;
```

clouds is PointF List
Also extendedPoints is PointF List.

Now in clouds in this case i have 37 indexs(points).

For example lets say in clouds in index 0 i have: x = 150 y = 200
And index 1 : x = 160 y = 250
So im using your method of ja72 and now extendedPoints contain 20 points:

The format of extendedPoints should look like:

```
index 0 : x = 150 y = 200
index 1 : x = 152 y = 210
index 2 : x = 155 y = 220
.
.
.
.
.
index 21 : x = 160 y = 250
```

Now that is one itertion.
The next one should take from clouds from the original List index 2 and index 3 and send them to your method and return another 20 points.

now extendedPoints should look like :

```
index 0 : x = 150 y = 200
index 1 : x = 152 y = 210
index 2 : x = 155 y = 220
.
.
.
.
.
index 21 : x = 160 y = 250
index 22 : x = 165 y = 255 ( this index 21 is the original index 2 of clouds )
index 23 : x = 166 y = 260
.
.
.
.
.
index 42 : x = 200 y = 300 ( this is the index 42 should be the original index 3 of clouds )
```

In other words i need to keep all the points coordinates of clouds in the same order they are in the original clouds List and add between each two points new 20 points.

In the end clouds should be with all its original points in the same order they was before but with added new 20 points in between each two points.

The problem is that your method make itertion over clouds only once not 37 times.
And also in the end each time the points are mixed pt1 and pt4 should be added as they were coming in the same order.

Comment: Point should have `x` and `y` coordinates. You are trying to create points which have only `x` or only `y`. What is your intent?

Comment: Consider renaming the method to `DistributePoints` as it disributes `N` points along the line between `pt1` and `pt4`.

Comment: Also it is not a good idea to have a `double` as a `for()` loop variable.

Comment: There is no need to cast to `double` and then to `float`, just keep all the math in `float`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code has a subtle bug. The end points are treated differently from the interior points (which go through the `Min()` and `Max()` process). Also it is not a good idea to use a `double` for a loop counter. Consider the code below as a cleaner version of your code:

```
public static List<PointF> DistributePoints(PointF pt1, PointF pt4, int number_of_points)
{
    List<PointF> result=new List<PointF>();
    float x_min=Math.Min(pt1.X, pt4.X), x_max=Math.Max(pt1.X, pt4.X);
    float y_min=Math.Min(pt1.Y, pt4.Y), y_max=Math.Max(pt1.Y, pt4.Y);
    if(number_of_points<2) throw new ArgumentException("Need Two Points At Least");
    for(int i=0; i<number_of_points; i++)
    {
        float scale=(float)i/(number_of_points-1);
        float x=x_min+(x_max-x_min)*scale, y=y_min+(y_max-y_min)*scale;
        result.Add(new PointF(x, y));
    }
    return result;
}
```

Which you use like:

```
{
    var res=DistributePoints(new PointF(100, 20), new PointF(10, 200), 11);
    // res = 
    // ( 10.0,  20.0)
    // ( 19.0,  38.0)
    // ( 28.0,  56.0)
    // ..
    // ( 91.0, 182.0)
    // (100.0, 200.0)
}
```

Comment: ja72 i tried your code but it will return 20 points only once. Second problem you put pt1 and pt4 in the wrong way. I need ot keep them as they was in the original order. Allways first pt1 then pt4. In your code result return 20 points and the first one is pt4 the last one is pt1.

Comment: @user3117033 please explain. What do you mean returns 20 points only once? What did you expect. Maybe you need to provide an example in the post of the expected result (like I put in my answer).

Comment: ja72 look above in my question the way im using it. Im doing FOR LOOP over the List clouds and call your method . clouds contain 37 indexs of points . In the end the List extendedPoint should contain like 37*20 points. First itertion in your method it get two points from clouds and return 20 points between this two points. Next itertion it should get the next two points from clouds and then again to create 20 points between them and the same for all the indexs in clouds thats 37.

Comment: ja72 i will update my question here with your method and how im using it.

Comment: Try `clouds.AddRange(DistributePoints(...));` to add the points returned by distribute into the running list `clouds`.

Comment: ja72 yes now its working but also now i have this problem as i described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20844917/why-im-getting-20-new-points-only-once some points are not belong to the clouds or for some reason draw in other place location out of the clouds .  line at an angle ; (geometry) diagonal Cant figure out why. like 20 points are drawed in diagonal . Strange.

Comment: So award this answer, update the other post with the new information and I can look at it there.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide `X` and `Y` in the constructor of `PointF`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.pointf.pointf(v=vs.110).aspx

```
extendedPoints = ExtendPoints(new PointF(clouds[i].X, clouds[i].Y), new PointF(clouds[i + 1].X, clouds[i + 1].Y),20);
```