# Why im getting 20 new points only once?

Tags: c#, winforms

First the idea the goal:
I have a method that get two points and a number of points to create and return me a List of points with the new number of points to create in between the points.

First problem is that for example in the first time pt1 is 181,172 and pt4 is 180,171
But in the result i see 20 points inside but the first one is:

180,171 and the last one is 181,172
And i need to keep it on the same way it was.
The given two points should be on the same indexs first: 181,172 and then in the end on index 02 180,171

The second problem is that its doing it only once return 20 points once only.
This is how im using the method:

```
for (int i = 0; i < clouds.Count - 1; i += 2)
{
    extendedPoints = DistributePoints(new PointF(clouds[i].X, clouds[i].Y), new PointF(clouds[i + 1].X, clouds[i + 1].Y), 20);
}

clouds = extendedPoints;
return clouds;
```

clouds now contain only 20 points but in the original clouds was with 37 points and and the method DistributePoints should take each time two points from clouds and add between the two points new 20 points.

The method:

```
public static List<PointF> DistributePoints(PointF pt1, PointF pt4, int number_of_points)
        {
            List<PointF> result = new List<PointF>();
            float x_min = Math.Min(pt1.X, pt4.X), x_max = Math.Max(pt1.X, pt4.X);
            float y_min = Math.Min(pt1.Y, pt4.Y), y_max = Math.Max(pt1.Y, pt4.Y);
            if (number_of_points < 2) throw new ArgumentException("Need Two Points At Least");
            for (int i = 0; i < number_of_points; i++)
            {
                float scale = (float)i / (number_of_points - 1);
                float x = x_min + (x_max - x_min) * scale, y = y_min + (y_max - y_min) * scale;
                result.Add(new PointF(x, y));
            }
            return result;
        }
```

But for some reason its adding painting more 20 points somewhere on the pictureBox points i didnt want.

The result im getting is:
I marked with black the points i dont need:

<sub>(click for larger view)</sub>
[image]

How can i fix it ?

The problem is here i think:

```
for (int i = 0; i < clouds.Count - 1; i += 2)
            {
                extendedPoints.AddRange(DistributePoints(new PointF(clouds[i].X, clouds[i].Y), new PointF(clouds[i + 1].X, clouds[i + 1].Y), 20));
            }
            clouds = extendedPoints;
```

If clouds contain 37 points(indexs) and i send it to the method 20 times in the end clouds should contain 740 points(indexs).
But for some reason clouds contain only 360 points(indexs).

37 * 20 = 740
Then why clouds in the end is containing only 360 points ?

So i have this problem that in the end clouds contain only 360 points and i have the other problem that its drawing 20 points in some place i didnt want it to be. strange.

EDIT**

Something i think is wrong in this code part:

```
for (int i = 0; i < clouds.Count - 1; i += 1)
            {
                extendedPoints.AddRange(DistributePoints(new PointF(clouds[i].X, clouds[i].Y), new PointF(clouds[i + 1].X, clouds[i + 1].Y), 20));
            }
            clouds = extendedPoints;
```

If im doing in the FOR += 1 then in the end clouds end with 720 points but then i see two sets of 20 points drawed on some other locations as a line format.

If im doing in the FOR += 2 then in the end clouds end with 360 points but then i see one set of 20 points drawed on some other location as a line format.

If im doing in the FOR += 3 then in the end clouds end with 240 points only but this time without those 20 points drawed on other location. But 240 points is not right i think it should end with 740 or 777 points in clouds.

EDIT**

ja72 this is what im getting now with your code:

[image]

This is how im drawing the points in the paint event:

```
public static void Paint(Graphics e, double currentFactor, float kilometers)
        {
            float distance = kilometers / (float)1.09;//289617486; // One pixel distance is 1.09 kilometer.
            Pen p;
            p = new Pen(Brushes.Green);
            if (points == null)
            {
                return;
            }


            foreach (PointF pt in clouds)
            {
                e.FillEllipse(Brushes.Red, (pt.X - distance) * (float)currentFactor, pt.Y * (float)currentFactor, 4f, 4f);
            }
```

In this case: kilometers = 0.0 and currentFactor = 1.0
Maybe something here with the paint event is wrong but i dont think so.

Comment: Have you tried running it in debug mode and _making sure_ that it's this method that's the culprit? From the looks of it, you're modifying a field of the class (`extendedPoints`); is it possible that this method is being called multiple times or somewhere else is modifying the `extendedPoints` collection? If possible, I'd recommend updating the method to have _no side effects_, that is, it's already returning a list. Build a _new_ list in the method and return it _or_ have it return `void` so it's clear it's changing state: doing both just produces confusion and bugs like this one.

Comment: I noticed your "usage"; I bet this is the fundamental issue. It looks like you're working with the same `List<PointF>` for each iteration. Try having it work with a new list, or clear the collection first.

Comment: Are you using `DistributePoints()` or `ExtendPoints()` ?

Comment: Note also the min/max stuff might be causing the interpolated middle points to be in the wrong order, or worse. Just use simple linear interpolation: `x = x1 + f * (x2 - x1)` where `f` ranges from 0 at the first point to 1 at the last point (in your case, `d` divided by the number of points). This formula works regardless of whether or not x1 > x2.

Comment: Dvnrrs tried but i didnt understand good maybe. Can you show me how is it suppose to look in my code after changing it please ?

Comment: ja72 ExtendedPoints . ja72 sorry i wrote you a commecnt on my other post according to you method DistributePoints.

Comment: ja72: ja72 i tried your code but it will return 20 points only once. Second problem you put pt1 and pt4 in the wrong way. I need to keep them as they was in the original order. Allways first pt1 then pt4. In your code result return 20 points and the first one is pt4 the last one is pt1

Comment: ja72 im looping with for over clouds and clouds have 37 points but your method after one time return 20 points only once and stop. It should return 20 points 37 times.

Comment: Don't use the min/max approach you're using now. You're always going to have a line that slopes downwards to the right (that is, both x and y will be growing) the way you've written it.

Comment: a72 and others i added my project to my skydrive. Maybe you can download it and see the problems. If im not wrong it should return in the end clouds should be with its original 37 points + 20*37 points in between each two points thats: 777 points. The other problem is those 20 points are draw in other location i didnt want them to be there

Comment: Lasse i tried before but i dont know how to convert it without using Max and Min. Can you show me how my code should look like without Max and Min please ?

Comment: Edited my question again. sorry.

Comment: in the future use the `SnippingTool.exe` program that comes with windows (in the `Windows\System32` folder) to take screenshots, it saves them as PNG and pre-cropped to make it a lot easier to upload images. Also look at the edit I made and how I wrapped your image with a link, that lets people click the image to get the full size version.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can best tell this is what you want:

```
public static List<PointF> DistributePoints(PointF pt_start, PointF pt_end, int number_of_points)
{
    List<PointF> result=new List<PointF>();
    float x_start=pt_start.X, x_end=pt_end.X;
    float y_start=pt_start.Y, y_end=pt_end.Y;
    if (number_of_points<2) throw new ArgumentException("Need Two Points At Least");
    for (int i=0; i<number_of_points; i++)
    {
        float scale=(float)i/(number_of_points-1);
        float x=x_start+(x_end-x_start)*scale, y=y_start+(y_end-y_start)*scale;
        result.Add(new PointF(x, y));
    }
    return result;
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<PointF> clouds=new List<PointF>();
    List<PointF> extended=new List<PointF>();
    // add N points to clouds
    // there are N-1 intervals
    for (int i=1; i<clouds.Count; i++)
    {
        extended.AddRange( DistributePoints( clouds[i-1], clouds[i], 20));
    }
    // extended now has (N-1)*20 points
}
```

Comment: ja72 updated my question with the result of what im getting according to your updated code. Still not working good. I iwll have to check my code again i dont know why it happen. you can see it here bigger: http://i.imgur.com/dQIsECn.jpg?1

Comment: ja72 i can also upload my project to skydrive maybe it will be easier to see it.